# How to paralellize nested (dependent) for loop in C, Open MP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm having trouble parallelizing a block of C code.

The block is something like this:

```
for(n = 0; n < N; n++)
  {
  for(x = 0; x < X; x++)
    {
    var_1[x] = var_1[x] * 3 * var_2[x];
    var_2[x] = var_2[x] * 2;
    }
  for(y = 0; y < Y; y++)
    {
    var_3[y] = var_1[y] * var_2[y];
    }
  }
```

That's not the actual code (it's for an assignment so I can't post the source code) but the problem is that the variables lie in a nested loop, and each iteration is dependent upon the previous.

Simply adding a #pragma omp for in front of the outer loop doesn't work because each thread's work begins at the initial values of var_1, var_2 and var_3.

Please let me know if I can explain any better! I'm quite lost.

Comment: So parallelise the inner loops.  For more useful help you'll have to post something a bit more representative of your real code, I think you have oversimplified matters.  For instance, in the loop over `x` each iteration does not depend on the previous one; its correctness depends on `var_1[x]` being calculated before `var_2[x]` but not on the order in which the `x`s are iterated -- there's no `var_[x] = function_f(var_[x-1])` or similar loop dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As HighPerformanceMark comments, the inner loop has no loop-carried dependency. This invites vectorisation first, parallelisation second, at least to me.
 **More importantly**, the cheapest computation is the one you never do in the first place. As it is written, `var_3[]` is never *read* in either loop. You can remove the second inner loop, and only compute `var_3[]` after the last iteration of the outer loop.
I suspect further performance gains are entirely academic. It seems to me that this algorithm will very quickly overflow (if used on integers), or lose precision (if used on floats), so the maximum number of iterations has to be small.